# Primitive polynomial and divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, divisibility

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $c(f)=1$ and $f$ is non-constant. Now suppose $h(x) \in\mathbb Z[x]$ be such that $h(x)=f(x)q(x)$  where $q(x) \in\mathbb Q[x]$.  Then I have to show that $q(x) \in\mathbb Z[x]$.

What I have tried by using Gauss lemma there exist $r , s \in\mathbb  Q$ such that  $f(x) =rf(x)sq(x)$ such that $rf(x) , sq(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$. But I can't show $r \in\mathbb Z$. I need some help. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the question as it is.... please consider editing it...

Comment: what is $c(f)$?

Comment: C(f) is the content of f @Ferra

Comment: I wrote upto my level best.The meaning of Z and Q are as usual i.e. Z=Set of all integers and Q= set of rational numbers @Praphulla Koushik

Comment: I know what $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are but i was not sure what $c(f) $ is... I did not understand your first line in second paragraph... why does there exists such $r,s$??

Comment: I applied Gauss lemma

Comment: c(f) means the gcd of the coefficients of f

Answer (score 1):

Assume all coefficients of $q$ are written in reduced terms. Let $d$ be the lcm of the denominators of $q$. Then $dh=fq'$ where $q'=dq\in \mathbb Z[x]$. Since the $c$ function is multiplicative, you get $dc(h)=c(q')$ which shows $d\mid c(q')$. This in particular implies that $d$ divides all coefficients of $q'$, which are the numerators of the coefficients of $q$. So suppose one of the coefficients of $q$ is $a/b$ for some $b>1$ and $(a,b)=1$. Then $b\mid d$, but on the other hand $d\mid a$, so $b\mid a$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $b=1$ and you have the claim.

Comment: I thought it many times ...I think it is not right

Comment: @Via I wrote gcd instead of lcm, you're right... now it should be ok

Comment: Yes I got it now..thank you @Ferra